# Uninstall evolution without uninstalling gnome-shell

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, evolution

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed and use it to develop software. I noticed in `htop` that there's two processes that eats a lot of memory,`/usr/lib/evolution/evolution-addressbook-factory` and `/usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory` -- using up 1G of virtual address space and 100MB of resident memory. I don't have any use for a calendar or address book. In fact, I have more important things to do with the memory and CPU time they consume. And importantly I absolutely do *not* want any application to try to integrate with a calendar or address book that I will never use. I want any application trying to do so to tell me that it's following broken ideas of security. So I want to uninstall them.

```
inetknght@develop:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Nothing to update or install. Neat, so the system is fully updated. I want to remove a package.

```
inetknght@develop:~$ dpkg -S evolution-addressbook-factory
evolution-data-server: /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-addressbook-factory-subprocess
evolution-data-server: /usr/lib/systemd/user/evolution-addressbook-factory.service
evolution-data-server: /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-addressbook-factory
inetknght@develop:~$ dpkg -S evolution/evolution-calendar-factory
evolution-data-server: /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory
evolution-data-server: /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess
```

So, both of the processes I want to remove are provided by the `evolution-data-server` package.

```
inetknght@develop:~$ sudo apt-get remove evolution-data-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  policykit-1-gnome
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  evolution-data-server gdm3 gnome-shell gnome-todo ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-session
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  policykit-1-gnome
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 24.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

Why does removing a package make apt-get want to install another??? And why should removing that package need to remove the whole shell?

In the past I have simply `chmod -x /usr/lib/evolution/*` and that worked temporarily. But an update was posted sometime ago and now the files have been replaced and are executable again. What is the real solution to uninstalling system components that I will never use? Why are there system components that provide address book and calendar facilities but don't have any configurability? There's no UI for these components. If I search for `evolution` in the activities menu then no results are returned. But if I search for `evolution` in the Ubuntu Software app then I see a result and it's *not installed*. So if it's not installed then how are these components here and running???

Comment: Gnome requires Evolution Data Server (E-D-S) whether you use it or not. No way around it. Complain to the Gnome developers about that choice (not us). Ubuntu has lots of other Desktops, none of which require E-D-S. Many users do appreciate the easy  personal-data integration that E-D-S provides.

Comment: Note that Evolution (the Email/Addressbook/Contact client) is not the same as E-D-S. They grew from the same project, and do very different jobs. Gnome does NOT require Evolution. Gnome does require E-D-S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is you can not because gnome-shell explicitly declares `evolution-data-server` as a Dependency,

```
apt-cache depends gnome-shell | grep evolution-data-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I know is not the answer (which is a don't do it).
But got to this thread because I deleted evolution-data-server and lost my GUI.
That was the only package in conflict.
I didn't find a straight answer so here is what worked for me and hope it helps.
Ubuntu 22.04.

```
dpkg --force-depends -r evolution-data-server
apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Or

```
apt install ubuntu-desktop-minimal
```

According to what was previously installed.